# Foreign Key conflict on INSERT statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, desktop-application

I'm developing a WinForm desktop application for users to input employees retirement data, using SQL Server 2008 as DB.

One of the tables that gets part of the user data has a reference to another table whose records were defined at design time, adding a Foreign Key constraint for consistency.

```
CREATE TABLE tbCongedo (
    ID int IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_ANAGRAFICA int NOT NULL,
    ID_TIPOLOGIA int NOT NULL,
    DECORRENZA datetime NOT NULL,
    PROT_NUM nvarchar(7) NOT NULL,
    PROT_DATA datetime NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE tbTipologia (
    ID int IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TIPOLOGIA nvarchar(20)
    );

INSERT INTO tbTipologia VALUES ('CONGEDO'), ('POSTICIPO'), ('ANTICIPO'), ('REVOCA'), ('DECESSO')

ALTER TABLE tbCongedo
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_tbCongedo_tbTipologia
FOREIGN KEY (ID_TIPOLOGIA) REFERENCES tbTipologia(ID)
```

Then, I have this code that should execute the `INSERT` statement

```
public int Insert(SqlConnection Connessione)
{
    using (SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbCongedo VALUES (@ID_ANAGRAFICA, @PROT_NUM, @PROT_DATA, @DECORRENZA, @ID_TIPOLOGIA); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", Connessione))
    {
        Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_ANAGRAFICA", ID_ANAGRAFICA);
        Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROT_NUM", PROT_NUM);
        Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROT_DATA", PROT_DATA);
        Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DECORRENZA", DECORRENZA);
        Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_TIPOLOGIA", ID_TIPOLOGIA);

        ID = Int32.Parse(Comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    }
    return ID;
}
```

but I'm given this SqlException:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tbCongedo_tbTipologia". The conflict occurred in database "Scadenziario_ver4_TEST", table "dbo.tbTipologia", column 'ID'

These are the data that I was trying to get inserted in the table:

```
ID_ANAGRAFICA = 2
ID_TIPOLOGIA = 0
PROT_DATA = {16/03/2018 00:00:00}
DECORRENZA = {16/03/2018 00:00:00}
PROT_NUM = 123456
```

Funny thing is that when I try to insert those same data manually through SQL Server Management Studio, I'm given no error at all.

Thanks.-

Comment: Is there a record for "0" in the FK table?

Comment: @Patrick Yes, those were added at design time. 0: Congedo, 1: Posticipo 2... and so on.

Comment: Pause the code at the `Execute` line, and look at the values you are about to try to insert.   Then query the FK table and make sure there is a matching value there already.   Something in your data isn't what you think it is, and you haven't investigated it yet.

Comment: I'd also double check that you're connected to the database you think you're connected to.

Comment: Given that you can insert this in SSMS it is obvious the issue in your application. You are passing some value that you don't think you are. And slightly off-topic here but you should avoid using AddWithValue since you are using ad hoc queries. It doesn't always interpret datatypes correctly. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem isn't in the data but in the `INSERT` statement itself. You are trying to insert the values to the wrong columns using the wrong order. To solve the issue you should either specify the columns in the `INSERT` statement or correct the order of the values. In your case the query will try to insert the value of `@PROT_NUM` in the `ID_TIPOLOGIA` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying fields: `(col_name1, col_name2, ...)`.

Without that the VALUES may not be applied as how you might hope. Variable names are NOT automagically matched with similarly-named columns.

So like this:

```
... new SqlCommand
(
    "INSERT INTO tbCongedo " +
    "       (ID_ANAGRAFICA, PROT_NUM, PROT_DATA, DECORRENZA, ID_TIPOLOGIA) "
    "VALUES (@ID_ANAGRAFICA, @PROT_NUM, @PROT_DATA, @DECORRENZA, @ID_TIPOLOGIA); " + 
    "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", Connessione
)
...
```

Comment: Good catch. I hadn't noticed that the column order is all over the place.

Comment: It's a Very Bad Habit not to include a column list in your INSERT statements.   I hope OP has learned his lesson about this.